# Given a sequence of integers, return the sum of all the integers that have an even index, multiplied by the integer at the last index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, integer, numbers

This is my solution and it passes some of the tests, but not all of them. Can anyone help me and explain why? Thank you :)

```
function evenLast(numbers) {
  let sum = 0;
  let lastNum = numbers.pop();
  let arr = numbers.filter(el => el % 2 === 0);

  
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += (arr[i] * lastNum);
  } 
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: What if the last number you popped was an integer at the even index ? Remember that `numbers.pop()` mutates `numbers`. Also you're checking the values and not index as highlighted by @Nina in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I will try with different approach.

Comment: It depends on whether the last index is even and should be included in the sum before multiplying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the index, not the value

```
let arr = numbers.filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 0);
```

And you could multiply the sum at the last step.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i]);
} 
return sum * lastNum;
```

---

A better approach takes only a single loop and sums the values by taking an increment of two.

```
function evenLast(numbers) {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 2) sum += numbers[i];

    return sum * numbers[numbers.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function evenLast(arr) {
    var lastarr = arr.slice(arr.length-1)
    //return lastarr;
    let newarr = [];
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
            newarr.push(arr[i]); 
        }
    }
            //return newarr;
            var sum1 =0; 
            for(i=0; i<newarr.length; i++) {
                var sum = newarr[0] * lastarr[0];
                var sum1 = newarr[1] * lastarr[0];
                //return sum;
               var  sum2 = sum1 + sum;
               //i++;
            } 
                return sum2;
}
console.log(evenLast([2, 3, 4, 5]))
```